# How can I get around specifying variables in decltype expressions?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-inference, lambda

Assume I have the following exemplary function:

```
template <typename Fn> auto call(Fn fn) -> decltype(fn()) {
  return fn();
}
```

The important thing about this function is that its return type depends on its template parameter, which can be inferred. So ultimately, the return type depends on how the function is called.

Now, we also have a test class:

```
struct X {
  int u;
  auto test() -> decltype(call([this]() -> double {this->u = 5; return 7.4;})) {
    return call([this]() -> double {this->u = 5; return 7.4;});
  }
};
```

as you can see, `X::test` calls `call`, returning the same return value. In this case, the return type is trivially given as `double`, but let's assume for a bit we didn't know what `call` does and that the lambda has a more complicated return type.

If we try to compile this, the compiler will complain, because we're using `this` at the top level (not in a scope that would allow an expression):

```
error: lambda-expression in unevaluated context
error: invalid use of ‘this’ at top level
```

However, I *have* to use the capture of the lambda which I pass to `call` in order to get `call`'s return type right. How would you suggest to get around this, while still leaving the lambda?

Note: Of course I could move the lambda to be an `operator()` of some helper type, which I instantiate with a copy of the `this` pointer, but I'd like to avoid that boilerplate.

Comment: I want to be at least gcc 4.5 compliant.

Comment: You can't put a lambda expression inside e.g. `decltype` (which is what the first error is alluding to), so you have another problem, too.

Comment: @LucDanton: Thanks. I didn't realise that. Would you consider that an extension of this question? Should I open a new one? Any chance to get around it, whatsoever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the real error to be concerned about is "lambda-expression in unevaluated context". You can't use a lambda in an unevaluated context because every lambda expression has a unique type. That is, if `decltype([]{})` were allowed it would deduce a different type than `[]{}` in some other context. I.e. `decltype([]{}) fn = []{};` wouldn't work.

Unless you want to just explicitly write the return type rather than have it deduced, I don't think you have any choice but to create a real type that you can use in the contexts you need, with whatever boilerplate that entails.

Although if changing `test` to not be a member function is acceptable then you could use the fact that lambda's can deduce their return type by omitting it if the body is only a single return statement:

```
template <typename Fn> auto call(Fn fn) -> decltype(fn()) {
    return fn();
}

struct X {
    int u;
};

int main() {
    auto test = [](X *x) { return call([x]() -> double {x->u = 5; return 7.4; });};

    X x;
    test(&x);
}
```

It would be nice if the trailing return type syntax for functions had the same property. I'm not sure why it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a made up (construed, artificial) question, since

- If you get the lambda from somewhere else, then it's named and no problem binding `this`.
- If you're not getting the lambda from somewhere else, then you know the result type.

In short, as the problem is currently stated (as I'm writing this answer) there's no problem except one imposed by your own will.

But if you insist on that, well, just pass `this` as an argument instead of binding it via the lambda definition. Then for the call to `call`, bind the argument. But, perhaps needless to say, since that only solves a made-up problem it's a real Rube Goldberg construction, a decent into over-flowering needless complexity that doesn't solve anything real outside its own intricacies.

What was the original *real problem*, if any?

Comment: The problem is not made up. Perhaps I fail to see your obvious solution (that's no sarcasm, I often overlook the obvious). Without looking at the definition of `call` what's the return type of `X::test`?

Comment: @bitmask: you need to know the def of `call` in order to use it. and you need to know your lambda in order to use it. problem solved, the return type in this case is `double`. If you really have to use an unknown `call`, just pass a dummy lambda (with same return type as the real one`) to the call in the `decltype`. Again, problem solved, because *you have all the necessary knowledge at the call site*.

Comment: Sorry, if Luc is correct in his comment on the main question, you can't put a lambda inside a `decltype` as you do. I didn't know. But check that out!

Comment: Wrong. The compiler needs to know the definition (well, the declaration, to be precise) of `call`. It may change. It may return complicated types that depend in non-trivial ways from the argument (as they do in my case). You would have to repeat part of the declaration of `call` in the declaration of `X::test`. What does your "sense of quality" tell you about that?

Comment: @bitmask: re my "sense of quality", it detects only hostility in your response. that's normal on SO, which is more about the social than the technical. read the comment you replied to again, but also read Luc's comment on the question itself (I wasn't aware of what he's saying)

Comment: Honestly no hostility intended. You were suggesting to duplicate code, so I wondered how that would be a good solution. I just wanted to hint at that. Sorry, if I offended you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't always copy-and-paste function body to `decltype`. The point of introducing late-specified return type was that you'll be able to somehow infer correct return type from arguments.
e.g. `auto f(T x) -> decltype(g(x)) { return h(), g(x); }`, not `-> decltype(h(), g(x))`

So, in your case, `double test()` is enough, because we know behavior of `call` and we know return type of lambda function we pass to it.
In more complex case, we should reduce code inside `decltype`, by using knowledge about `call` and other stuff.